# Документация по XNA

Tags: xna, c#, документация

Где взять **Русскую** документацию по XNA, желательно перевод с MSDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Геймдевеперов развелось... [Введение в XNA](http://www.intuit.ru/department/se/intxna/).

Answer (score 1):

[Также статья в MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc163420.aspx)

[Онлайн книга](http://netlib.narod.ru/library/book0052/toc.htm)

[Иван Андреев — XNA для начинающих](http://www.it-portfolio.net/Post.aspx?id=73)

[Онлайн книга по XNA 4.0](http://unmail22.narod.ru/Books/Learning_XNA4/Learning_XNA4.html)